# Ubuntu does not detect my VAIO webcam

Tags: webcam

I've installed Ubuntu 12.10. I'm using a Sony VAIO VGN-FE52B laptop which I bought in Japan. Since I installed Ubuntu (and accidentally overwrote the VISTA recovery partition) I have not been able to get my webcam working. I've tried both lsusb and lspci which gives me the following:

```
lsusb

Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0451:2036 Texas Instruments, Inc. TUSB2036 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 054c:01bb Sony Corp. FeliCa S320 [PaSoRi]

lspci

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/PM/GMS, 943/940GML and 945GT Express Memory Controller Hub (rev 03) 
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/PM/GMS, 943/940GML and 945GT Express PCI Express Root Port (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 02)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 1 (rev 02)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 2 (rev 02)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 3 (rev 02)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 4 (rev 02)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 02)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 02)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 02)
00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 02)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 02)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev e2) 
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801GBM (ICH7-M) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 02)
00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) IDE Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801GBM/GHM (ICH7-M Family) SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 02)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family SMBus Controller (rev 02)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G73 [GeForce Go 7600] (rev a1)
06:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection (rev 02)
0a:03.0 CardBus bridge: Texas Instruments PCIxx12 Cardbus Controller
0a:03.1 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Texas Instruments PCIxx12 OHCI Compliant IEEE 1394 Host Controller
0a:03.2 Mass storage controller: Texas Instruments 5-in-1 Multimedia Card Reader (SD/MMC/MS/MS PRO/xD)
0a:08.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation PRO/100 VE Network Connection (rev 02)
```

I don't see my webcam.

I tried the Sony website but because it's all in Japanese it's a little tricky but they don't seem to provide a single driver, and I'm sure they won't provide anything support for Ubuntu. So I wanted to find the webcam model and search elsewhere for the driver.

Is there any other way that I can detect the webcam? Maybe if I can figure out which webcam it is but if Ubuntu is not even detecting the device I don't know how I'd update the driver anyway. I don't want to buy a separate webcam but thinking I may have to.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The fix found at https://bitbucket.org/ahixon/r5u87x

Enter the code, 1 command at a time, into a terminal window.

```
sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev libusb-dev build-essential gcc automake mercurial
hg clone http://bitbucket.org/ahixon/r5u87x/
cd r5u87x
make
sudo make install
sudo r5u87x-loader --reload
```

The loader will automatically be run on boot when it detects your webcam.

Comment: The link is dead now. I was able to find something on archive.org, but I don't remember what. For people facing this issue today, try https://github.com/p6/R5U87X.